# integrate google maps with bing map wpf control

Tags: c#, wpf, google-maps, wpf-controls, bing-maps

I was trying to integrate bing map wpf control with google map. I did that in windows phone few days back here is tutorial : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/153467/Google-Maps-for-Windows-Phone-7-using-Bing-Map-Con which I followed.

I tried similar to do that with wpf control. But its not working and giving error in xaml part.

Its giving this error : **The member "TileSources" is not recognized or is not accessible** and this Error **The attachable property 'TileSources' was not found in type 'MapTileLayer'.**

I tried this too but no luck : [Load custom tiles in Bing maps on WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11747160/load-custom-tiles-in-bing-maps-on-wpf)

Have anyone done that before.

Thanks

Comment: You should perhaps know that Google *does not allow* to use their maps in this way, at least last time i asked them about a year ago. You must not use this in a production application.

Comment: Besides the Google Terms of Use issue, you must know that the Bing Maps WPF Control API is quite different from the Silverlight (WP7) one. What exactly do you mean by "no luck" at trying the WPF solution?

Comment: whats the difference between wpf control api and silverlight api. What we should do if we have to use google map in wpf application?

Comment: Get an overview of the Bing Maps APIs [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd877180.aspx). Google maps in production WPF app? Don't know if [this](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-net/) may help. I'd suggest not to use Google Maps at all, go for OpenStreetMap instead.

Comment: what is the difference between silverlight bing map control and wpf bing map control, why the same solution can't work.

More or less your solution is also exactly same.

Comment: Why don't you read the API documentation? Then you'll easily recognize all the differences.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11766869/1136211) on [Load custom tiles in Bing maps on WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11747160/1136211) you could use a Google-style map Uri like below.

```
<m:Map>
    <m:Map.Mode>
        <!-- set empty map mode, i.e. remove default map layer -->
        <m:MercatorMode/>
    </m:Map.Mode>
    <local:MyTileLayer
        UriFormat="http://mt0.google.com/vt/x={x}&amp;y={y}&amp;z={z}" />
</m:Map>
```

EDIT: I just tested this and for some reason i don't understand the Bing Maps WPF control won't display any map tiles, just gray background. I also checked the generated map URIs, which are indeed valid. Try for example http://mt0.google.com/vt/x=16&y=10&z=5.

Running this with an OpenStreetMap URI format `http://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png` works as expected.

Comment: okay, based on your answers and old post. I created map control and integrated with google. But when I run I dont see anything at all on screen not even single tile.

Comment: See my edit. I haven't got the faintest idea what's going on there.

Comment: You might also want to check out [this control](http://wpfmapcontrol.codeplex.com/). It provides an alternative to the Bing Maps WPF Control and does not require you to purchase an API license key. There are also no special terms of use and no limitations on the content you want to display. It works well with Google Maps tile URIs (although still not allowed by Google of course).

Comment: Ask Google! Their terms of use simply disallow direct access to their tile servers. You must use their API.

Comment: @sunder think of it like that: you use the tiles in your app, there is no Google logo placed in your app, so you use their resources without even specifying the source. It's like making a clone of StackOverflow website with all it's content, but without the StackOverflow logo (or even worse, with a custom logo claiming ownership of the content)

Comment: I will not specify their logo in my application, that I haven't said. I love to specify it.

Comment: @sunder You should target your comment to `@Tiby`, otherwise he wouldn't even realize that you wrote something here.