# How to change design of Bing Maps (tiles)?

Tags: c#, wpf, bing-maps

I'm looking for a convenient way to use Bing Maps in my WPF application, but I can't seem to figure out how to create my own design and how to implement it. I would like to change all the colours etc, just like you can with the Google Maps map-editor.

Is there a tool that I can use to design my own visual style and export it (so I can use it offline)?

Kind regards,
Niels

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gingemonster was right. I used CloudMade to design my own style, and it will give you a Style ID and API key and a specific URL that can be used to fetch up your tiles.

I then used this the code given in this topic:
[Load custom tiles in Bing maps on WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11747160/load-custom-tiles-in-bing-maps-on-wpf)

Works great :),
Thanks
Niels

Answer (score 1):

Bing doesnt current have a styled map service and neither Bing or Google's license agreement would allow you to download the tiles for offline usage.

I recommend you look at cloudmade.com, who do provide styled maps and allow downloading of tiles. You'll then need another wpf map control but have a look round on google and there are a number of projects

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In my understanding it is possible to use custom map tiles in Bing Maps right? I guess CloudMade could work with that?>