# How to load Google Maps in wpf window?

Tags: wpf, google-maps, devexpress

Is it possible to load Google Maps in wpf window? If yes how can i do this?
I'm using visual studio-2010 and DevExpress tool.
This code i found from DevExpress official site for openstreetmaps.

```
const string roadUrlTemplate = @"http://{subdomain}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{tileLevel}/{tileX}/{tileY}.png";
```

Comment: You mean besides hosting it in a WebBrowser control?

Comment: yes, want it to load in wpf window.

Comment: Although you may create a custom TileSource for Bing Maps (as shown in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11766869/1136211)) or any other map control which downloads map content from Google, their terms and conditions disallow such usage.

Answer (score 3):

An easy way is to use the WebBrowser control.
In XAML add:

```
<WebBrowser x:Name="wbMaps" Source="https://www.google.com/maps"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are not limited to using Google Maps then take a look at the Bing Maps WPF control for a truly native WPF map solution:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh750210.aspx

If you need to use Google Maps you can of course use a web browser control and create an interlop to communicate between C# and JavaScript however if you want a native WPF solution then take a look at some open source solutions like the following:

http://greatmaps.codeplex.com/

https://github.com/ericnewton76/gmaps-api-net

Comment: The Bing Maps are great but there is no street side view :(

Comment: Bing Maps just released streetside in it's newest JavaScript map control. It also has had streetside available for UWP (Windows 10) apps for a year now.

Comment: bing did not update his maps constantly, in my region I'm seeing map have a 10 years

Comment: Which API are you using? Check the web SDK, that's their main map control. The WPF control docs and SDK hasn't been updated. The download link for that SDK doesn't even work anymore.