# Is it possible in WPF to see on the map the city names after you add a polygon on it?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, bing, bing-api

Unlike UWP, in **WPF**, we do not have zindex for map layers.

I need to draw a polygon with full opacity over various areas on the map. This means that I am creating a layer and I am adding in over the very first map layer (the map itself) which displays the name of the cities, countries and so on.

I want to see the name of the countries, without reducing the opacity. A solution would be to create a layer of polygons, and put it **under** the very first layer. That's not possible in WPF, at least to my knowledge, I've already tried.

For a better understanding, attached you my find a screenshot, with half opacity to show you that I want the full name of Portugal, for example.[image] I want to see the full name with the opacity set to 1.

Here's the code spinet, just for your information, however I am having a concept/approach challenging rather than a technical one.

```
     MapPolygon lcMapPolygon = new MapPolygon
                            {
                                StrokeThickness = 1,
                                Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White),
                                Locations = lcBasicGeopositions,
                                Fill = new SolidColorBrush(GetFillColor(lcDataValue)),
                                Opacity = 0.5, //this MUST be set to 1, NOT LESS!!
                                Tag = new MapPolygonTag (pmLayerName, lcPlacemark.Name, lcDataValueString)            
                            };
   myMap.Children.Add(lcMapPolygon);
```

Comment: why don't you draw the polygon layer first and then draw the map layer? seems pretty easy to do

Comment: In my code I draw only one layer, the polygon one.

Comment: where does the map come from? background? if so you can draw it in a layer and problem solved

Comment: It comes from XAML. Let's assume that it is declared with the name myMap, as I put it in my code snippet. A map contains layers, and I'm adding a (only one) layer which contains polygons (for various map areas - Spain, Portugal, Asia etc.)

Comment: A very common way to add things into a canvas is to use an itemscontrol with a canvas as itemspanel. Bind a collection of viewmodels to the itemssource and template into ui objects using datatemplating. There is an implicit z-index lowest first. Each thing you add goes on top of another. This is how I do maps in our map editor for GeneralStaff. Each tree, road house etc is a viewmodel templated out.  This is a very simple example of a forest with trees on top  https://imgur.com/8NsH0uC

Comment: The itemcontainer is the thing to position. Bind canvas.left and canvas.top on that.

Comment: You may create a custom map tile layer for the WPF Bing Maps control, as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11766869/1136211). Then use it as an overlay layer that contains labels only on an otherwise transparent background, e.g. http://maps.stamen.com/terrain-labels/#12/37.7706/-122.3782