# How can I display a dynamically generated image on top of Bing Maps WPF control?

Tags: c#, wpf, bing-maps

I've been searching for a bit on how I can display scalable media on top of a WPF Bing Maps MapControl, but I cannot find any example code or a solid solution to my problem.

Here is the control documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/bing/wpf-control/hh750210(v=msdn.10)

I'm generating a grid that represents a density map, which then becomes a bitmap image. This is fine, I have the image. How can I overlay this image onto the map with some transparency such that the user is able to move and scale the map if necessary?

My initial thought is to create a tile layer and add it to the map control since I know the size of each square and its lat/long, but there doesn't seem to be many examples of anyone doing this online. The documentation is somewhat scattered as well, and more heavily focused on UWP:

This appears to be exactly what I need, but it is a UWP control - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/maps-and-location/overlay-tiled-images#overlay-tiles-from-local-storage

This also appears to be useful but only has XAML code, no actual C# showing what the buttons do...
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/bing/wpf-control/hh868033(v=msdn.10)

Okay, the next thought was to make the image, then scale it appropriately and overlay the media onto the map using this documentation, but again, only XAML code is shown as an example. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/bing/wpf-control/hh868032(v=msdn.10)

Has anyone done something like this in WPF? I'm a bit lost.
Thank you.

Comment: Does it need to be Bing Maps? Maybe use an open source library that provides such a feature.

Comment: I would much prefer it Clemens, but if it isn't possible I suppose I'll have to switch.

Comment: The WPF map control supports tile layers, just like the UWP map control. The UWP map control is what is recommended for any new development, but if you're stuck with WPF for some reason, you can use the MapTileLayer in the WPF control. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/bing/wpf-control/hh750701(v=msdn.10). Loading the tiles from local storage, or generating them on the fly should work.

Comment: Thanks Duncan, I got it working with some tinkering with TileSource and MapTileLayer referencing this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11747160/load-custom-tiles-in-bing-maps-on-wpf